# Sort a vector of strings by substrings?

Tags: c++

I have a vector containing a number of strings of the same form:

```
'12345 QWERTY'
'23456 ASDFGH'
'34567 ZXCVBN'
```

I need to sort them by code (int type) and by names (string type). I am thinking of using the `.substr()` function to ignore the numbers. Is there a way I could use this within the sort function?

One attempt is to create a mapping function to compliment 'sort()':

```
bool mapFunc(string a, string b) 
{
return a.substr(6) < b.substr(6));
}
```

plug into the sort function:

```
sort(begin, end, mapFunc);
```

where 'begin' and 'end' are both iterators pointing to the beginning and end of my vector.

Please correct me if Ive made any mistake here:)

Comment: You can pass your custom functor, to be used while sorting, to `std::sort` function, did you try to do so?

Comment: Yes use a lambda expression with std::sort.

Comment: Did you read the examples of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort ?

Comment: Instead of using a vector try to use map or pair data type which makes your sorting easier

Comment: most naturally would be to parse those strings into a vector of `struct { int id; string qwerty;}` then you can sort them however you want easily

Comment: Is the integer part always the same length?

Comment: If the integer part is always the same (known) length, you may use c++17's std::string_view if available for your comparison functor. If it isn't, re-parsing your strings whenever you want to compare them sounds a bit annoying, so parsing them beforehand as user463035818 suggests seems like the best option (even if you have to rebuild the strings afterwards, although that's really sad and inconvenient to store records/tuples/... in string form :( ).

Comment: The integer part is always the same lengths this is true for all strings in the vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that using [std::lexicographical_compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) would be more efficient that extracting a substring.

What [std::lexicographical_compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) does is it compares substrings ***in place*** so you don't pay the cost of copying them out.

Something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> v
{
    "12345 QWERTY",
    "23456 ASDFGH",
    "34567 ZXCVBN",
};

std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](std::string const& a, std::string const& b){
    return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(a), std::begin(a) + 5, std::begin(b), std::begin(b) + 5);
});

std::cout << "By first column" << '\n';
for(auto const& s: v)
    std::cout << s << '\n';

std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](std::string const& a, std::string const& b){
    return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(a) + 6, std::end(a), std::begin(b) + 6, std::end(b));
});
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of this kind of thing then you can wrap it up in a special comparator like this:

```
struct substring_compare
{
    std::size_t from;
    std::size_t len;

    substring_compare(std::size_t from, std::size_t len)
    : from(from), len(len) {}

    bool operator()(std::string const& a, std::string const& b) const
    {
        // sanity checks
        assert(from + len <= a.size());
        assert(from + len <= b.size());

        auto beg_a = std::begin(a) + from;
        auto end_a = beg_a + len;

        auto beg_b = std::begin(b) + from;
        auto end_b = beg_a + len;

        return std::lexicographical_compare(beg_a, end_a, beg_b, end_b);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v
    {
        "12345 QWERTY",
        "23456 ASDFGH",
        "34567 ZXCVBN",
    };

    // start at position 0, comparing 5 characters
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), substring_compare(0, 5));

    std::cout << "By first column" << '\n';
    for(auto const& s: v)
        std::cout << s << '\n';

    // start at position 6, comparing 6 characters
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), substring_compare(6, 6));

    std::cout << "By second column" << '\n';
    for(auto const& s: v)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
By first column
12345 QWERTY
23456 ASDFGH
34567 ZXCVBN

By second column
23456 ASDFGH
12345 QWERTY
34567 ZXCVBN
```

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track by passing a custom predicate to `std::sort()`. You just need to flesh it out more:

```
void split(const string &s, int &code, string &name) {
    size_t idx = s.find(' ');
    code = stoi(s.substr(0, idx));
    name = s.substr(idx+1);
}

bool mapFunc(const string &a, const string &b) {
    int code1, code2; 
    string name1, name2; 
    split(a, code1, name1);
    split(b, code2, name2);
    if (code1 == code2)
        return name1 < name2; 
    return code1 < code2;
}
```

This will sort the vector items by their numeric codes first, and will sort by name only for items with the same code value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `functor` (function object):

```
struct Compare_By_Number
{
  bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const
  {
    std::istringstream a_input_stream(a);
    std::istringstream b_input_stream(b);
    int a_value, b_value;
    a_input_stream >> a_value;
    b_input_stream >> b_value;
    return a_value < b_value;
  }
};
```

You can then pass an instance of the function, as per [the `std::sort` example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

**Edit 1:  Standalone function**
An alternative is to place the code inside a standalone function and pass the function:

```
bool Order_By_Number(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
{
    std::istringstream a_input_stream(a);
    std::istringstream b_input_stream(b);
    int a_value, b_value;
    a_input_stream >> a_value;
    b_input_stream >> b_value;
    return a_value < b_value;
}

std::vector<std::string> database;
//...
std::sort(database.begin(), database.end(), Order_By_Number);
```

The fundamental concept is to return `true` if the first parameter comes before the second in your ordering.

Comment: Your functor does not track any state information, so using a functor is overkill when a standalone function will suffice

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  I edited my answer for the standalone function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing functionality that `std::pair` provides (comparison operator). So implement conversion function:

```
std::pair<int,std::string> convert( const std::string &str )
{
     int id = 0;
     std::string name;
     std::istringstream is( str );
     is >> id >> name;
     return std::make_pair( id, name );
}
```

then your comparator function is trivial:

```
bool compare( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
     return convert( s1 ) < convert( s2 );
}
```

Comment: Just a small nitpick - `operator>>` stops reading on whitespace, so if the strings ever happen to have spaces in the names, eg: `'12345 ABC DEF'` then `>> name` won't work. You can use `std::getline()` instead: `is >> id >> std::ws; std::getline(is, name);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think it is OPs job to provide proper example of data or describe it in question,I provided info based on existing information. Anyway this should be enough for OP to implement accordingly. PS OP says "number of strings of the same form" so I think I can assume there is no space.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better have a `std::vector<std::pair<int, string>>` to void such complications.
Otherwise you should create a comparative function and pass substrings.

Comment: Yes I'd love to do this, but I have to do this because it's part of my assignment requirement:-(

Comment: @Z.Yang what in you assignment forbids you to use a pair or a vector? That would be strange rules (especially as you seem to be allowed to use `std::sort`)

Comment: I would guess that the assignment has been set in order to practise using functors or lambdas (can't tell which).

Comment: I think its meant for string manipulation mostly, its quite hard to tell without the full context. I don't know what lambdas are hh

Answer (score 0):

To set up the question, we have a vector of strings:

```
vector<string>myVec;

vector<string>::iterator vecBegin=myVec.begin(), vecBegin=myVec.end();
```

One attempt is to create a mapping function to compliment 'sort()':

```
bool mapFunc(string a, string b) 
{
return a.substr(6) < b.substr(6));
}
```

plug into the sort function:

```
sort(vecBegin, vecEnd, mapFunc);
```

where 'vecBegin' and 'vecEnd' are both iterators pointing to the beginning and end of my vector.

This will sort the vector of strings by substrings. The vector can be accessed using iterator:

```
vector<string>::iterator currentVec;
for (currentVec=vecBegin; currentVec<vecEnd; ++currentVec) 
{
// Do things
}
```

Comment: I figured out the problem immediately after posting the question (even though Ive been working on it for many hours now). This is the answer indeed because it worked as I compiled and ran it.